# Convert Excel data to json using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sample input which looks like this:
[sample input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCQoy.png)

I need a function to convert Excel table into a json with the following expected output.
[Excepted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IHqh.png)

Checks to be considered:

1. Anything after field name, if data is filled for those it should be considered else don't include in json as shown in sample output json
2. Anything in mandatory column, if no data is filled add them as an empty dictionary as shown in sample output.

How do I approach this with nested dictionary concept?

```vb
Sub jsonConverter()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tests")
    
    Dim mainheading As Range, itm As Range
    Set mainheading = ws.UsedRange.Columns(1)
    Set itm = mainheading.Cells(1)
    While Len(itm.Value2) > 0
        Debug.Print itm & " : " & itm.MergeArea.Address(0, 0)
        Set itm = itm.MergeArea.Offset(1)
    Wend
End Sub
```

Loop through sheet 1 and got all the col A values from the merged cells. Need to create a nested dictionary with this.

[Sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oV2p7k_1vWsF6jfOYj9LfvC-NELqMLRk/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=108827571916573584534&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: Can anyone answer. Pls

Comment: Your chances of getting an answer would be increased if you would share that sample data as a downloadable xlsx file.  No one wants to type that out in order to be able to even start on a workable piece of code

Comment: added the sample data. Now can anyone help

Comment: I can take a look at it but I’m away from a pc for a week or so